# Using click() and setTimeout() jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I am just wondering what would be the best way to make my jQuery function a little bit more DRY.

Here is an example of my code:

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".landing-page-header-container").addClass('reveal-signup');
        $(".landing-page-vehicle-left-container").addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig');
        $(".landing-page-vehicle-right-container").addClass('animated fadeInUpBig');
        $(".landing-close-video").removeClass('reveal-landing-close-video');
      },8000)
    });
    $('.landing-close-video').click(function(){
      $(".landing-page-header-container").addClass('reveal-signup');
      $(".landing-page-vehicle-left-container").addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig');
      $(".landing-page-vehicle-right-container").addClass('animated fadeInUpBig');
      $(".landing-close-video").removeClass('reveal-landing-close-video');
    });
```

Now as you can see I am repeating myself quite a bit here because the setTimeout function is doing exactly the same thing as the click function.

Is there anyway I can combine these two functions?

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable.

```
function do_stuff() {
  $(".landing-page-header-container").addClass('reveal-signup');
  $(".landing-page-vehicle-left-container").addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig');
  $(".landing-page-vehicle-right-container").addClass('animated fadeInUpBig');
  $(".landing-close-video").removeClass('reveal-landing-close-video');
}

setTimeout(do_stuff, 8000);
$('.landing-close-video').click(do_stuff);
```